# Changing the color of an axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

Is there a way to change the color of an axis (not the ticks) in matplotlib? I have been looking through the docs for Axes, Axis, and Artist, but no luck; the matplotlib gallery also has no hint.
Any idea?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

When using figures, you can easily change the spine color with:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('#dddddd')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('#dddddd') 
ax.spines['right'].set_color('red')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('red')
```

Use the following to change only the ticks:

- `which="both"` changes both the major and minor tick colors

```py
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
```

And the following to change only the label:

```
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('red')
```

And finally the title:

```
ax.title.set_color('red')
```

Comment: `ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')` seems to change the color of both the tick and the label...

Comment: Is it possible to use `ax.yaxis.label.set_color('grey')` in such a way that only the ticks from `y1` to `y2` change their color, and the others remain unaltered?

Comment: Any Idea on how to change the color of points to be scattered?

Comment: @FaCoffee You can set the tick label colors independently of the tick color by calling `set_ticklabels()` and passing the `kwarg` `color`. Like so: `ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0], color = 'k')`

Comment: @Jonathan's comment works for me. It is critical to use the `colors` parameter, not the `color` parameter (note the `s`).

Comment: Note, that I found `plt.style.use('dark_background')` helpful to do this kind of thing on the fly.

Answer (score 26):

You can do it by adjusting the default rc settings.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rc('axes',edgecolor='r')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: Matplotlib also has a [context manager](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html#temporary-styling) which allows for temporary changes to the rc parameters http://stackoverflow.com/a/41527038/2166823

Comment: Thanks @joelostblom . I am using a dark background on my browser and jupyter notebook. One single line did the whole job. From the docs for context: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('dark_background')`

Answer (score 23):

For the record, this is how I managed to make it work:

```
fig = pylab.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
for child in ax.get_children():
    if isinstance(child, matplotlib.spines.Spine):
        child.set_color('#dddddd')
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting edge color for all axes globally:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = '#ff0000'
```