# twinx kills tick label color

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I am plotting a double plot with two y-axes. The second axis `ax2` is created by `twinx`. The problem is that the coloring of the second y-axis via `yticks` is not working anymore. Instead I have to `set_color` the labels individually. Here is the relevant code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fill_between(data[:,0], 0, (data[:,2]), color='yellow')
yticks(arange(0.2,1.2,0.2), ['.2', '.4', '.6', '.8', ' 1'], color='yellow')
ax2 = twinx()
ax2.plot(data[:,0], (data[:,1]), 'green')
yticks(arange(0.1,0.6,0.1), ['.1 ', '.2', '.3', '.4', '.5'], color='green')
# color='green' has no effect here ?!
# instead this is needed:
for t in ax2.yaxis.get_ticklabels(): t.set_color('green')
show()
```

Resulting in:

[image: colored_ticklabels]

This issue only occurs if I set the tick strings.

```
yticks(arange(0.1,0.6,0.1), ['.1 ', '.2', '.3', '.4', '.5'], color='green')
```

Omit it, like here

```
yticks(arange(0.1,0.6,0.1), color='green')
```

and the coloring works fine.

> Is that a bug (could not find any reports to this), a feature (?!) or
>   am I missing something here? I am using python 2.6.5 with matplotlib 0.99.1.1 on ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're doing... (What exactly do you mean by "double plot"? `twinx`/`twiny`, subplots, or something else entirely?) Can you post some example code or an example image of the problem and/or what you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. I tracked down the problem to the use of `twinx` and condensed the question description. Also a graphic is added.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever it's worth, you code works fine on my system even without the `for` loop to set the label colors.  Just as a reference, here's a stand-alone example trying to follow essentially exactly what you posted:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
num = 200
x = np.linspace(501, 1200, num)
yellow_data, green_data = np.random.random((2,num))
green_data -= np.linspace(0, 3, yellow_data.size)

# Plot the yellow data
plt.fill_between(x, yellow_data, 0, color='yellow')
plt.yticks([0.0, 0.5, 1.0], color='yellow')

# Plot the green data
ax2 = plt.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, green_data, 'g-')
plt.yticks([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1], color='green')

plt.show()
```

[image]

My guess is that your problem is mostly coming from mixing up references to different objects.   I'm guessing that your code is a bit more complex, and that when you call `plt.yticks`, `ax2` is not the current axis.  You can test that idea by explicitly calling `sca(ax2)` (set the current axis to `ax2`) before calling `yticks` and see if that changes things.

Generally speaking, it's best to stick to either entirely the matlab-ish state machine interface or the OO interface, and don't mix them too much.  (Personally, I prefer just sticking to the OO interface. Use `pyplot` to set up figure objects and for `show`, and use the axes methods otherwise. To each his own, though.)

At any rate, with matplotlib >= 1.0, the `tick_params` function makes this a bit more convenient.  (I'm also using `plt.subplots` here, which is only in >= 1.0, as well.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
yellow_data, green_data = np.random.random((2,2000))
yellow_data += np.linspace(0, 3, yellow_data.size)
green_data -= np.linspace(0, 3, yellow_data.size)

# Plot the data
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(yellow_data, 'y-')
ax2.plot(green_data, 'g-')

# Change the axis colors...
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='yellow')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='green')

plt.show()
```

[image]

The equivalent code for older versions of matplotlib would look more like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
yellow_data, green_data = np.random.random((2,2000))
yellow_data += np.linspace(0, 3, yellow_data.size)
green_data -= np.linspace(0, 3, yellow_data.size)

# Plot the data
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(yellow_data, 'y-')
ax2.plot(green_data, 'g-')

# Change the axis colors...
for ax, color in zip([ax1, ax2], ['yellow', 'green']):
    for label in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_color(color)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The issue with the ignored `color=` tag occurs (oddly) only when I explicitly set the label strings: `yticks(arange(0.1,0.4,0.1), ['.1 ', '.2', '.3'], color='green')`. The set strings work, the color does not. Does your first minimal example also work if you specify it? E.g. `plt.yticks([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1], ['foo', 'bar'], color='green')`.

Thanks for pointing out the different matplotlib styles (matlab vs. oo). I will read it up a bit more to improve the consistency of my code.