# Bar chart of positive and negative values

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want the negative bars to be facing downwards, and the positive upwards, with the x-axis(0-line) passing right between them. I tried this

```
chart = fig.bar(x, negative_data, width=35, color='r')
ax2 = plt.gca().twinx()
ax2.bar(x, positive_data, width=35, color='b')
```

But instead, I get merged red and white bars, both facing downwards. It seems that the arrays negative_data/positive_data only specify the height of the bar, but how do I specify the orientation? I need something to specify the coordinates of the  tops of each bar.

Also, how do I make the widths be something reasonable, possibly dynamic as the graph is resized by user?

Here is an example of problematic widths:

```
x = [250, 1500, 2750, 4250, 6000, 8500, 13200]
negative_data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
positive_data = [3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

How can I make the plot of those look nice?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You don't need to add a twin axis, you can plot both bar charts on the same axis like this:

```
x = range(7)
negative_data = [-1,-4,-3,-2,-6,-2,-8]
positive_data = [4,2,3,1,4,6,7,]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, negative_data, width=1, color='r')
ax.bar(x, positive_data, width=1, color='b')
```

[image: bar chart with negative an positive y values]

Bars with a width of one will fill the axes and will scale with the figure as it is resized.

Comment: Cool, works! Do you have any idea what I do about the widths though?

Comment: What do you want the widths to look like?

Comment: Either the bars touching each other, or with a really small gap between them. Right now I get extremely thin vertical lines. They also look black, maybe because they are so thin, I cannot see the color.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like you have too many bars to be displayed in the figure. You might need s different type of plot or a larger figure.

Comment: But it only shows a couple bars, and they are all just vertical lines. I have 7 bars per plot.

Comment: I updated my answer with a example of seven bars in a plot to show that it's possible. Without seeing your x an y data and the size of the axes I can't give you a better answer.

Comment: Cool. Can my problem have something to do with the fact that I have multiple subplots, and also within the same subplots, the bars can be of different orders of magnitude? But I don't know why the height difference can have to do with the width.

Comment: Here is the problematic data:
x = [250, 1500, 2750, 4250, 6000, 8500, 13200]
negative_data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
positive_data = [3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

How do I make this look nice?

Comment: Try width = 1000. Then set the x and y limits of the axes.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer. I have one more unrelated question: do you know how I can change the color of the frame of a subplot?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778954/elegantly-changing-the-color-of-a-plot-frame-in-matplotlib)

Comment: is there no way to make this more automated?  if you don't know which data is going to be positive or negative relative to the midline?