# Set tick egde color in matplotlib rc

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I want to write a callable function that sets my matplotlib rc Parameters uniformly for all my different plots. So far it is just a block that I copy to every file and boils down to this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

grey = '#808080'

mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 0.3
mpl.rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = grey
```

I am doing this to have thinner axes and to make my data stick out by having everything else a little grey-ish. But I cannot find a way to set the tick edge color to grey in the rc. I am looking for something like

```
'axes.tickedgecolor'
```

which doesn't seem to exist, sadly.

A way of doing it without rc is described here: [Elegantly changing the color of a plot frame in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778954/elegantly-changing-the-color-of-a-plot-frame-in-matplotlib)

I hope somebody can help, thanks!

Edit: Just to clarify: I found the option

```
mpl.rcParams['tick.color'] = '#808080'
```

but it also changes the tick labels, which I want to remain black!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I found a little workaround to my answer that fulfills my needs:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

grey = '#808080'

mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 0.3
mpl.rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = grey
mpl.rcParams['xtick.color'] = grey
mpl.rcParams['ytick.color'] = grey
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelcolor'] = "black"
```

Although `xtick.color` also changes the label color, you can overwrite the label color afterwards.

Edit: Somehow this only works for a single plot. For a figure with 6 subplots it does not work.

Edit2: I couldn't get it to work with rcParams, so I changed the ticks during the subplotting routine

```
ax.tick_params('both', length=2, width=0.3, which='major', color=grey)
```

This made it work.