# Set the colour of matplotlib ticks on a log scaled axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following the advice of [Changing the color of the axis, ticks and labels for a plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761623/changing-the-color-of-the-axis-ticks-and-labels-for-a-plot-in-matplotlib) I have managed to set the colour of the spine, label, numbers and ticks of my graph using:

```
ax.spines['left'].set_color('#FF9000')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('#FF9000')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#FF9000')
```

However, when I set the axes of my graph to log scale the ticks revert to black again.

For example:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('#FF9000')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('#FF9000')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#FF9000') <-- now only half works
```

This draws the numbers the colour I want (so I know the command still does something) but doesn't affect the ticks.

Is there a way to set the colour of log scaled ticks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works correctly on my system (runniing very close to the current git master):

You just need to add the kwarg `which='both'` [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params)

```
figure()
ax = gca()

ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('#FF9000')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('#FF9000')

ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#FF9000', width=5, which='both')
```

I made the ticks thicker to make it easy to see the color.

In a log scale, the small ticks are minor ticks, and by default `tick_params` only changes the major ticks, you just need to tell it to do both or explicitly do each (major and minor) separately.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, that fixed it. I shall accept this answer as soon as it lets me.