# Matplotlib How to change x and y ticks background color?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change the background color of my x axis and y axis.

I tried
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('k')

But I get an error
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_axis_bgcolor'

Upon further internet search I found out that 'set_axis_bgcolor()' has been depreciated. A GitHub thread on this topic suggests using 'set_facecolor()', which does not address ticks background color.

How can I change x or y ticks background color?

Comment: you want to change the colours of the ticks themselves? Or do you want to change the colour of the axis spine?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761623/changing-the-color-of-the-axis-ticks-and-labels-for-a-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you tmdavison.