How to display a matplotlib figure in a Jupyter notebook with transparent background?
While it is possible to render a figure inline with transparent background in a Jupyter console, I cannot set the figure background to transparent in a Jupyter notebook.
Why? Any ideas?
See below for a minimal reproducible example.

Code to create a transparent matplotlib figure
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#00FF0000")
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], facecolor="#FF000000")
plt.plot(range(10), [x**2 for x in range(10)])

It works in a Jupyter console.
jupyter qtconsole --style monokai


But it does not work in a Jupyter notebook (tested in VS Code)


Maybe this vscode-jupyter issue thread can help: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7470

Okay, thanks. They mention that they're "not likely going to make a change here in the near future"

While not transparent, the addition of this line works in Jupyter to set the color to better match what you see with qtconsole:
fig.patch.set_facecolor([0.08, 0.08 , 0.08, 1]); # based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/61891800/8508004;

OP's example code incorporating that in JupyterLab 4.1 with the theme 'JupyterLab Dark' toggled on:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#00FF0000")
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], facecolor="#FF000000")
plt.plot(range(10), [x**2 for x in range(10)])
fig.patch.set_facecolor([0.08, 0.08 , 0.08, 1]); # based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/61891800/8508004;
#fig.patch.set_alpha(1.0); # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708018/8508004


That can be further modified to let the other parts show better by defining the colors for the spines, ticks, and labels, like so:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#00FF0000")
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], facecolor="#FF000000")
plt.plot(range(10), [x**2 for x in range(10)])
fig.patch.set_facecolor([0.08, 0.08 , 0.08, 1]); # based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/61891800/8508004;
#fig.patch.set_alpha(1.0); # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708018/8508004
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('#dddddd') # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850717/8508004
ax.spines['top'].set_color('#dddddd')  # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850717/8508004
ax.spines['right'].set_color('#dddddd')  # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850717/8508004
ax.spines['left'].set_color('#dddddd')  # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850717/8508004
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#dddddd')  # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850717/8508004
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#dddddd')  # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850717/8508004
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('#dddddd')  # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850717/8508004
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('#dddddd')  # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850717/8508004


Alternative: Let Matplotlib stylize to match dark style
Keep in mind also that matplotlib has a 'dark_background' style you can set, see 'Dark background style sheet' in the Matplotlib documentation and an answer to SO post 'Dark mode plots in Jupyter Notebook - Python'. Adding one line, plt.style.use('dark_background'), to the OP's code:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#00FF0000")
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], facecolor="#FF000000")
plt.plot(range(10), [x**2 for x in range(10)]);


Keep in mind this method is nice because it applies the styling to all the plots following that line, and so you can add it near the top of notebook to control all the plots.
However, note that the style also includes changes to the palette of line colors that Matplotlib cycles through. You can easily override that default line color by specifying the color for the line, like so:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#00FF0000")
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], facecolor="#FF000000")
plt.plot(range(10), [x**2 for x in range(10)], color="#1f77b4"); # fix based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709394/8508004 ; color value from https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colors.html


For more about colors in Matplotlib see here and here. The latter being the page where it spells out the color codes corresponding to the main line color cycle.

Note: To remove the frame around the plot, you may wish to use ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], facecolor="#FF000000", frame_on=False) to limit the features you have to color match.

Thanks. frame_on is just noise – I forgot to remove it from my example.

Note when using plt.style.use('dark_background') with Jupyter Notebook Version 7.1.2 with code from  here  where I added the use of plt.style.use('dark_background'), I noticed I had to run the cell twice to get it to respect the 'dark-background' look for the main part of the plot actually. (The main part of the plot background stayed white on first pass.)
